# How to get the counts of measurement in QSIM simualtor

Tags: qiskit, entanglement

I had generate Bell State, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle - |10\rangle)$ now when I measured that in $Z$ basis how can I get the state of individual qubit separately and not the probability of the combined state of the system.

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import DensityMatrix, partial_trace
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
qc1.x(0)
qc1.x(1)
qc1.h(0)
qc1.cx(0,1)

qc1.measure(0,0, basis='X')
job1 = execute(qc1, backend, shots= 1024 ,**options_without_noise)
result1 = job1.result()
prob = result1.get_counts()
print(prob)
```

**The above code had been written in qiskit using dm simualator developed by IISC whose git repo is https://github.com/indian-institute-of-science-qc/qiskit-aakash.git**
The counts method is not working saying no counts
and when trying to display to density matrix using the code below

```
prob = result1.results[0].data.densitymatrix
```

it result into the combined density matrix using the code after measurement

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with the 0th qubit only; one can similarly get counts for 1st qubit only.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

qc1 = QuantumCircuit(2,1)
qc1.x(0)
qc1.x(1)
qc1.h(0)
qc1.cx(0,1)
qc1.measure([0],[0])

sim = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
counts = execute(qc1, sim).result().get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts, figsize=(9,5))
```

[image: histogram of the measurement results for qubit 0]

Comment: This is using aer simulator i asked dm simulator of qsim...through aer its straight forward use shots = 1 u would get exactly 0 or 1 once

Comment: Apologies, I have missed that. If I understand correctly, you can dig out the probabilities for the state of the full system of 2 qubits in your example, i.e., p(final state=|00>), p(final state=|01>), etc. Let us say that you are interested in computing the probability of the rightmost qubit being in the state |0>. To do this you simply need to add p(final state=|00>) + p(final state=|10>). I hope this helps.